# Not importing modules except the default python3 on autostart

Tags: python, autostart

I want to run a python program on Nvidia Jetson (os: ubuntu) as soon as I plug in the power.

So I created a file like ~/.config/autostart/myscript.desktop which contains:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=myscript
Comment=myscript
Icon=gnome-info
Exec=python /your/path/script.py
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=

X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=0
```

So this is working absolutely fine when the modules I'm importing are the ones that come with python3 on default. But on importing modules like matplotlib.pyplot, tensorflow and firebase, it logs this error:

```
No module named tensorflow
No module named matplotlib.pyplot
No module named firebase
```

I checked the root libraries and all the libraries are present there as well but I can't understand why this is happening...

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: Are you using virtual environment?

Comment: Have you tried changing the command to `python3`?

Comment: Please check python versions in your system might be possible you are running different version of python on `python` command and different on `python3`

Comment: @Galunid no I'm not using virtual environment

Comment: @RishabhKumar and Adam... U both were right...silly error from my side...thanks

Comment: just one more help tho, I need to execute this command `export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1` in the terminal everytime before I run the program. So how I should execute this on autostart? Should I add a line like Exec?